# How to convert if statement to ternary operator?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Im trying to convert if statements to ternary operator

Here's my code:

```
if($today >= $visa_expiry) {
     echo "style='background-color : red; font-weight: bold; color: white; font-size: 13'";
}

if($today <= $visa_expiry) {
     echo "style='background-color : yellow; font-weight: bold; color: white; font-size: 13'";
}

if($today == $visa_expiry) {
     echo "style='background-color : green; font-weight: bold; color: white; font-size: 13'";
}
```

to ternary operator

can someone help me? Thank you

NOTE: that my if statement is just an example

Comment: Are you sure the above is correct? If `$visa_expiry` will be `$today` it will execute all three `echo`es.

Comment: you shouldn't, it should be an if\else if\else

Comment: @TeKo just an example sorry i will edit my post

Comment: Yes. If you're overwhelmed with syntax constructs already, don't pick the least readable one. Moreover shouldn't inline styles be used for that, but CSS classes.

Comment: If you really must; here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: *"Im trying to convert if statements to ternary operator"* - I don't see any attempt at what you tried.

Comment: adrian, please consider accepting one of the provided answers by clicking the tick mark. This way, your question will be marked as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround would be to use another ternary when the preceding ternary return false:

```
<?php
$today = 5;
$expiry = 7;
$visaexpiry = ($today < $expiry ? 'yellow': ($today ==$expiry? 'green': ($today>$expiry? 'red': 'nothing')));
echo $visaexpiry;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see why you would want to use a ternary here. As others have mentioned, this should be an `if`/`else if`/`else`. Additionally, in your example, all three conditions could be met at the same time.

Anyway, here is a simplified example of one possible way of expressing this with ternary operators:

```
$bg = "green"; // default, assuming $today == $visa_expiry
$bg = $today > $visa_expiry ? "red" : $bg;
$bg = $today < $visa_expiry ? "yellow" : $bg;
```

Note that this *will* evaluate both conditions, even if none is met, and assign the `$bg` variable to itself up to *two times*. Not nice, but a working solution.

How to go about this with nested ternary operators has been shown by [Mawia HL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40074843/3316645)